# How to read this hover syntax in css?

Tags: html, css

How to read a syntax like `.nav-menu li:hover ul`?
How is it different from `.nav-menu li ul:hover`?
I've searched w3schools but all the examples there are of the latter type.
Can anyone explain?
Below is the code that I've implemented for creating a dropdown submenu.

HTML

```
<ul class="nav-menu">
 <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Retrievals</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
       <li><a href="#">Data Listing</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Web Scheduling</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Google Maps Application</a></li>
    </ul>         
 </li>
 <li><a href="#">Reporting</a></li>
```

CSS:

```
.nav-menu li    
{
    width: 150px;  
    float: left;  
}
.nav-menu li ul 
{
    display: none;  

}               
.nav-menu li:hover ul   
{
    display: block; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First rule: `.nav-menu li:hover ul` apply css to `ul` once you hover parent `li`.

Second rule: `.nav-menu li ul:hover` apply css to `ul` once you hover `ul` element.

Answer (score 3):

```
.nav-menu li:hover ul
```

- an unordered list
- which is a descendant of a hovered list item
- which is a descendant of an element that is a member of the nav-meny class

---

```
.nav-menu li ul:hover
```

- a hovered unordered list
- which is a descendant of a list item
- which is a descendant of an element that is a member of the nav-meny class

---

You'd be unlikely to notice any practical difference with your specific HTML since the only list items you have that contain an unordered list contain nothing except a single unordered list.